# Excluding CROSS JOIN result from SELECT *

Tags: java, sql

I'm getting the following error.

```
Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'app_id'
```

It only happens when I try to include all results (because there are two app_id's). I can exclude the app_id from key_table by specifying which table or by doing "application.*".

Only problem with application.* is that there is a text field which is not supported by ENGINE=MEMORY. MySQL ignores this text field usually when quoting "*" but not when quoting "tablename.*".

Can someone give me a simple solution to this?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pparsreporting.CurrentApplications ENGINE=MEMORY
(
SELECT *, getApplicationsForRespID.app_id2 AS app_id2,
planning_scheme.markus_ra, planning_scheme.metro_or_rural

FROM application
INNER JOIN key_table ON key_table.app_id = application.app_id
INNER JOIN planning_scheme ON planning_scheme.ps_code = application.planning_scheme

CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT key_table.app_id AS app_id2, planning_return.resp_authority AS resp_id
    FROM key_table
    INNER JOIN planning_return ON key_table.return_id = planning_return.return_id

)getApplicationsForRespID

WHERE application.app_id = getApplicationsForRespID.app_id2
AND key_table.is_current = 1
```

);

SELECT * FROM pparsreporting.CurrentApplications

Comment: Why don't you just specify each of your field names?

Comment: Because there are many.

Comment: My best advice, write them once and be done with it :)  There isn't any way to select * minus a column.  If you really don't feel like typing, you can use group_concat with information_schema to copy and paste...

Comment: There's other a thousand columns (I didn't design it)

Comment: Plus there are new fields being added, but I don't know the names.

Comment: Maybe this can help -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffb60/3 -- dynamic SQL might be your best option though if the columns are changing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to loop though each table name and exclude the one I didn't want. Messy I know but it works.

```
String EachTable = "";
    Statement GetTableNames = mDatabaseConnection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = GetTableNames.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM pparsdb.application LIMIT 1");
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

    // The column count starts from 1
    for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++ ) 
    {
        EachTable += ",application." + rsmd.getColumnName(i);
    }

    System.out.println(EachTable);
```